# Почему вопросы бывают на засыпку?

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Интересно, почему каверзные вопросы называют "вопросами на засыпку", а синонимом слова "провалиться" является слово "засыпаться" — например, "засыпаться на экзамене".
Чем засыпаться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А почему обязательно ***чем**?
Вариантов, того, что может сделать на экзамене нерадивый ученик. В гимназические времена он вернее всего мог зарезаться (порезаться), потом - пролететь, убиться, умыться... всего уж и не вспомню.

Сыпать (кого?) - весьма и весьма образно. С одной стороны сыпаться - явно передаёт зыбкость, ненадежность, неустойчивость...
С другой передает процесс засыпания, закидывания...

Comment: >потом - пролететь, убиться, умыться... всего уж и не вспомню.

И ещё вспоминается "*завалить* экзамен". Как-то близко: *завалить*, *засыпаться*.

Comment: Cыпать (кого?) не  говорят.  Можно  засыпать  чем-то  и  кого-то (  что-то ). Выражение  "засыпать  вопросами"  мне  представляется  первоисточником  выражения  "засыпаться  на  экзамене".  Полностью  согласен  с  Марк Из(ом).

Answer (score 5):

Идёт экзамен. Студент ответил и преподаватель начинает задавать уточняющие вопросы. Один, другой, третий... Вопросы **сыпятся** как из рога изобилия. В конце концов студент не находит правильного ответа и "засыпается", не сумев ответить на билет, который в общем-то знает.

**Вопрос на засыпку** из той же оперы - это трудный вопрос, поставленный с целью застать собеседника врасплох, поставить его в сложное положение. Т.е. Вопрос с целью "засыпать".